# ClassNotFoundException on Tomcat Server

Tags: tomcat7

I am using this [tutorial](http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/tomcat_howto.html) to set up Tomcat Server. After I have put the `HelloServlet.java` in classes and Web.xml in the WEB-INF folder and I'm giving the command

localhost:9999/hello/sayhello

On the browser. I'm always getting `ClassNotFoundException`. If anyone can tell me where am I going wrong.

I'm using JDK1.6.0_30, and Tomcat7 for my sample application.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the compiled `HelloServlet.class` file (not the .java file) in the `WEB-INF/classes` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Compile `HelloServlet.java` and place the output class file `HelloServlet.class` into

```
<TOMCAT_HOME>\webapps\hello\WEB-INF\classes\HelloServlet.class
```

Answer (score 0):

In your 'WEB-INF' of 'classes' folder place the .class files and if your using JDBC, jsp's just Copy the .jar executable files into 'lib' folder. and make sure that xml file should contain the proper information.

you should follow below Web Application Directory Structure
WEB-INF/ --

1. `web.xml`  --xml file
2. `classes/` ---classes folder here we keep .class files Myservlet.class
3. `lib/`  ---lib folder here we keep all .jar files. Myapp.jar

   Welcome.html
   Welcome.jsp

Answer (score 0):

One thing you should check is that, the HelloServlet.class should be in a package. Looks like you have a long way to go with Servlet and JSP... I recommend Head First Servlet and JSP for your reference.